# oledb datatable update using paramaters failing

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I am trying to write the update command for a oledb dataadapter.  I have had a variety of errors.  I think my stumbling point is the stupid field names that I can do nothing about.
Perhaps someone can see my mistake?

The Database is access
  The table has many columns but I only want to update one.
  the column [Transaction Seq] is an AutoNumber
  the column to be updated [Code (IAO)] is text - 255 long

Error: Parameter [@Code (IAO)] has no default value.

my code:

```
oDAtblBound.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSql, oCon)
Dim builder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(oDAtblBound)
builder.QuotePrefix = "["
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
oDAtblBound.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
oDAtblBound.Fill(oTables, "tblBound")

cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblBound SET [Code (IAO)] = [@Code (IAO)] WHERE [Transaction Seq] = [@Transaction Seq]", oCon)

cmd.Parameters.Add("[Code (IAO)]", OleDbType.Char, 255, "[Code (IAO)]")
parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("[Transaction Seq]", OleDbType.Char, 255, "[Transaction Seq]")
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
oDAtblBound.UpdateCommand = cmd
```

Comment: Your use of parameters is messed up.  You need to set a .Value for the first one to what you want to the update value.  If [Transaction Seq] is an AutoNumber, why do you define the it as Char?  That one has no `.Value` either. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why you want to make your life difficult using column names and parameter names with spaces is beyond me.

Comment: Steve that makes two of us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to.....

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblBound SET [Code (IAO)] = @Code_IOA WHERE [Transaction Seq] = @Transaction_Seq", oCon)

cmd.Parameters.Add("Code_IAO", OleDbType.Char, 255, "Code (IAO)")
parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("Transaction_Seq", OleDbType.Char, 255, "Transaction Seq")
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
oDAtblBound.UpdateCommand = cmd
```